# ActionBar Overlaying Not Working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use the [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) to enable ActionBar Overlaying, but is not working

The action bar is not transparent and the layout is below the ActionBar

Result:
[image: Result]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Style

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

main_layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#AABBCC"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is said in the documentation of Developer Guide to set the windowActionBarOverlay  in your "Application Theme" which extends the a  parent theme(AppCompat in this case)

Comment: I changed and still not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the windowActionBarOverlay attribute in the Appcompat theme to true, the relativeLayout you're drawing only starts from the top it knows, which is below the action bar. It needs to be set in the main style, not in the actionbarstyle

Then you can set the android:background in the toolbarstyle to transparent for the desired effect

To show some code we use in our projects to get a transparent toolbar:

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle.Transparent" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

mind, the toolbar style is set on a toolbar in xml, which is later set as the actionbar.

Comment: Hello ThMBc, can you show me some code?

Still not working

Comment: With this code the overlay works, but I have no actionBar. I set the background color to "#338660" to be sure.

Comment: this is because this theme's parent is a NoActionBar theme, we use toolbars. So if you leave the .NoActionBar on the parent value you should get the normal actionbar.